# Is it worth encrypting files being stored on a server for distribution?

Tags: encryption

I'm creating a site for distributing software to clients. We're implementing lots of security bells and whistles on it to reasure the clients that software they're running wont have been tampered with. 
I'm toying with the idea of encrypting the files we upload to the server, but I'm not sure if there's much point conisdering the overhead it entails. The files are decrypted anyway when being transmitted to the client. As well as this, if a hacker gets into the server and replaces the encrypted files, they can also change any hashes we made of the files to check they havnt been manipulated. 
So... is it worth encrypting the uploaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh security.

How can the client be sure they're talking to the correct server.
How can the server be sure they're talking to a legal client.
How can the user be sure they're not using a compromised client etc.

Is the server in your custody or is it a shared server. How volatile is the data and is datatheft an acceptable risk or not.

Please expand your current situation. Do you use encrypted communcation. Is the communcation over internal or external lines. Do you thrust the server support team.

Answer (score 3):

You should sign rather then encrypt your files.

When using [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure), it is the act of encrypt (or encrypt a hash of) your file with your private key, instead of doing so with the receiver's public key.

Then everybody that download the file can verify that the file was not tampered with.

File encryption is useful when either you share a secret with your
receivers, or that you have their public key available. Typically it
is not useful in case of file distribution as you describe it.

Comment: I agree completely with this answer.  Get a code-signing cert from a vendor with certs built into your target platform, protect it, use it to sign your deliverables, and then you can deliver your software from anywhere and the client can be satisfied of the security.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer with a question: *what is the point in encypting files on the server when you don't have any control over what the clients will do with the decrypted versions anyway*?